# numpy argsort when elements are the same

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I have the following array:

```
array([0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
    0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
    0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
    0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.78772666e+02, 6.35416628e+02,
    1.16901104e+03, 1.79252306e+03, 2.52110498e+03, 3.37246243e+03,
    4.36728470e+03, 5.52974748e+03, 6.88810037e+03, 8.47535341e+03,
    1.03300792e+04, 1.24973505e+04, 1.50298353e+04, 1.79890767e+04,
    2.14469887e+04, 2.54876040e+04, 3.02091156e+04, 3.57262634e+04,
    4.21731224e+04, 4.97063611e+04, 5.85090485e+04, 6.87951035e+04,
    8.08144926e+04, 9.48593053e+04, 1.11270852e+05, 1.30447958e+05,
    1.52856655e+05, 1.79041511e+05, 2.09638855e+05, 2.45392250e+05,
    2.87170558e+05, 3.35989054e+05, 3.93034103e+05, 4.59691985e+05,
    5.37582589e+05, 6.28598773e+05]))
```

If I use numpy argsort, I get

```
array([ 0, 13, 12, 10,  9,  8,  7, 11,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  6, 14, 15, 16,
    17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
    34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
   dtype=int64)
```

I want this array in increasing order (i.e., something like array([0,1,2,3,.....])) when elements are equal (i.e. the relative order of equal items preserved), but argsort assign values in a weird way.

Can you suggest the best way to avoid this issue?

Comment: Please read the documentation, and check the argument `kind`; 'stable' may be what you are looking for.

Comment: "weird way" is only in the eye of the beholder. What is the specific use case where you need your output in this specific order?

Comment: @9769953 'stable' works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments by @9769953:

```
np.argsort(a, kind='stable')
```

*stable* sorts sustain the relative order of the equal items in the original array. You could end up with a slower sorting algorithm, however, depending on your array. *quicksort* which is the default mode is **NOT** a stable sort.

output:

```
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
       34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49])
```